# How do I prevent nginx from redirecting to HTTPS in this particular setup?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a somewhat messy setup (no choice) where a local computer is made available to the internet through port forwarding. It is only reachable through [public IP]:8000. I cannot get a Let's Encrypt certificate for an IP address, but the part of the app that will be accessed from the internet does not require encryption. So instead, I'm planning on making the app available from the internet at `http://[public IP]:8000/`, and from the local network at `https://[local DNS name]/` (port 80). The certificate used in the latter is issued by our network's root CA. Clients within the network trust this CA.

Furthermore, some small changes are made to the layout of the page when accessed from the internet. These changes are made by setting an `embedded` query param.

In summary, I need:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
|      Accessed using      |  Redirect to (ideally)   | URL args |            Current state             |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| http://a.b.c.d:8000      | no redirect              | embedded | Arg not appended, redirects to HTTPS |
| http://localhost:8000    | no redirect              | embedded | Arg not appended, redirects to HTTPS |
| http://[local DNS name]  | https://[local DNS name] | no args  | Working as expected                  |
| https://[local DNS name] | no redirect              | no args  | Working as expected                  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

For the two top rows, I don't want the redirection to HTTPS, and I need `?embedded` to be appended to the URL.

Here's my config:

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server api:5000;
}

# Connections from the internet (no HTTPS)
server {
    listen 8000;
    listen [::]:8000;

    server_name [PUBLIC IP ADDRESS] localhost;

    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        # Do not allow access to /admin/ from the internet.
        return 404;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/static/rest_framework/;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/static/admin/;
    }

    location /files/media/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/media/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend/;
    }

    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/frontend/;
        # I want to add "?embedded" to the URL if accessed through http://[public IP]:8000.
        # I do not want to redirect to HTTPS.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.html?embedded =404;
    }
}

# Upgrade requests from local network to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;

    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    server_name [local DNS name] [local IP] localhost;

    # This works; it redirects to HTTPS.
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}

# Server for connections from the local network (uses HTTPS)
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name [local DNS name] [local IP] localhost;

    ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/certificates/global.pass;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/privatekey.key;

    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend/admin/;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/static/rest_framework/;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/static/admin/;
    }

    location /files/media/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/media/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        # Proxy to backend
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass http://channels-backend/;
    }

    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {    
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';    
        expires off;    
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/frontend/;
        # Do not add "?embedded" argument.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.html =404;
    }
}
```

The server serves both the frontend and an API developed using React and Django RF, in case it matters. It's deployed using Docker.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I commented out everything except the first server (port 8000), and requests are still being redirected to `https://localhost:8000` from `http://localhost:8000`. I don't understand why. I'm using an incognito tab to rule out cache as the problem.

**Edit 2:** I noticed that Firefox sets an `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` header with the initial request to `http://localhost:8000`. How can I ignore this header and **not** upgrade insecure requests? This request was made by Firefox, and not the frontend application.

**Edit 3:** Please take a look at the below configuration, which I'm now using to try to figure out the issue. How can this possibly result in redirection from HTTP to HTTPS? There's now only one server block, and there's nothing here that could be interpreted as a wish to redirect to `https://localhost:8000` from `http://localhost:8000`. Where does the redirect come from? Notice that I replaced some parts with redirects to Google, Yahoo and Facebook. I'm not redirected to any of these. I'm immediately upgraded to HTTPS, which should not be supported at all with this configuration. It's worth mentioning that the redirect ends in `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`. The certificate is accepted when accessing `https://localhost/` (port 80) using the original configuration.

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server api:5000;
}

# Server for connections from the internet (does not use HTTPS)
server {
    listen 8000;
    listen [::]:8000 default_server;

    server_name localhost [public IP];

    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    ssl off;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        # Do not allow access to /admin/ from the internet.
        return 404;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/static/rest_framework/;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/static/admin/;
    }

    location /files/media/ {
        alias /home/docker/backend/media/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend/;
    }

    location / {
        if ($args != "embedded") {
            return 301 https://google.com;
            # return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri?embedded;
        }

        return 301 https://yahoo.com;
        # root /var/www/frontend/;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.html =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try dyndns so that you have a proper DNS for your IP.

Comment: @Shiv Thanks for the tip. Just to clarify, the port (8000) is essential. The public IP is used to access multiple services, depending on the port. Any DNS record would need to contain the port information, which is impossible, as far as I'm aware, or am I mistaken?

Users won't be aware of the host name as the app will be embedded on a website with a proper DNS name, so it's considered non-essential and therefore unlikely to get approved, depending on the price.

Comment: No ports have nothing to do with DNS. DNS is only a replacement for IP addresses plus it has some extra attributes like for MX records you have DMARC and SPF.

Comment: I thought so. So there is no way for me to get a DNS record for this server, as it's available at port 8000, and not 80, which means no HTTPS on the public portion of the app (served at `[public IP]:8000`), which is fine, except for my redirection problems.

Comment: You can write two different nginx configuration. One for incoming requests from outside and one for inside. That is a simple solution I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would change the result. If I include a different config file, aren't they simply combined in memory as if they were a single configuration? I'm sure there's an error in my configuration that's causing my issue, and not a limitation of nginx or using a single config.

Comment: No two different nginx configuration represent two different servers. Just that you cannot bind to same port. So if I were you I will have one port which is needed for outside config and another for my local one.

Comment: Presumably your `?embedded` parameter is used client-side so setting it in Nginx without an external redirect is pointless.

Comment: @RichardSmith That makes sense. So if the `?embedded` parameter is missing, should I `return` the requested URL with the parameter added? I suppose I could check if it's present using a regex, but I know for a fact that `?embedded` is the only parameter that will ever be used, so I can simply check if there are any args at all, and if not, redirect to the same URL with the argument. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You could add this to the `server` block: `if ($args != "embedded") { return 301 $uri?embedded; }`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Because I don't want the `?embedded` added for URLs in the other defined locations (like `/api/` and `/admin/`), I added it in the `location /` block, before the `root` and `try_files` directives.

Even with this, and having removed the servers for port 80 and 443 entirely, I'm still redirected to `https://localhost:8000` with no argument added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boy, do I feel stupid.

In my `docker-compose.yml` file, I had accidentally mapped port 8000 to 80:

```
  nginx-server:
    image: nginx-server
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: .docker/dockerfiles/NginxDockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
      - "0.0.0.0:8000:80"  # Oops
```

So any request on port 8000 was received by nginx as a request on port 80. Thus, even a simple config like...

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    return 301 https://google.com;
}
```

... would result in an attempt to upgrade to HTTPS (causes include unexpected caching of redirects, possibly default behavior, etc.) on port 80. I was thoroughly confused, but fixing my compose instructions fixed the problem:

```
  nginx-server:
    image: nginx-server
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: .docker/dockerfiles/NginxDockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
      - "0.0.0.0:8000:8000"  # Fixed
```